# How to get the VNC connection status?

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, vnc, vnc-server

I have been looking to find a way for my Qt application to know if a VNC connection is active.

How/can I get a VNC connection status?

This is an embedded Linux application.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point would be to look into the Qt sources at `src/plugins/gfxdrivers/vnc/qscreenvnc_p.h`; there a class `QVNCServer` is declared that also defines a `isConnected()` method which appears to do exactly what you need.

The crucial point, however, is to access that method from your application code; as can be deducted from the filename suffix `_p` the classes in that header are private (read: internal) to the Qt libs and not part of the public interface. Accordingly they are not documented in the reference, and I haven't found a public method to get the current `QVNCServer` object, nor any other VNC related instance that could provide a pointer to that object.

My suggestion is that you start with the related public interface in `src/plugins/gfxdrivers/vnc/qscreenvnc_qws.h`, which incorporates the server class as part of a `QProxyScreen` subclass, and work onwards from there to get an idea how the VNC server instance is created, and where the pointer to it is handled. You may be able to add a method to the `QVNCScreen` interface which allows you to get the connection state from your application. However you'll have to patch the Qt sources and rebuild the libraries.

Getting the `QScreen` object in application code is easy:

```
foreach(const QScreen* s, QScreen::instance()->subScreens())
{
    if(s->classId() == QScreen::VNCClass)
        //Here you can cast the screen instance and call a method on it
}
```